# Carry out equations using Google Sheet Script to update database values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, find, replacewith, gs-vlookup

So I'm trying to create a simple Elo model for our table tennis league at work, I'm using the spreadsheet to generate match ups and then depending upon the winner going in and manually updating the rankings.

I attempted to try and do this (As seen below) but I was blissfully unaware that set.formula was definitely not the correct coding to be using.

Is there a way for me to carry out what I've outlined below, I essentially want to be able to click a button for Player A or Player B and have their Elo rank update on the back end and then generate a new match combination? Also how do I update the record based on a variable? Everyone has a unique player number but is there a function similar to VLOOKUP that will let me find a record and perform a formula?

I've put as many sheet callouts in the code below as I can:

```
var sheet =SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Data");
var cell = sheet.getRange("=VLOOKUP("!MatchC18,A:C,3,False")
cell.setFormula ("=SUM(VLOOKUP(!MatchC18,A:C,3,FALSE)+!MatchA6*(1-E$4))");
cell.setFormula ("=SUM(VLOOKUP(!MatchE18,A:C,3,FALSE)+!MatchA7*(0-F$4))");

var sheet =SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Match');
var cell = sheet.getRange ("C18");
cell.setFormula("=TRUNC(RANDBETWEEN(100,632))");

var sheet =SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Match');
var cell = sheet.getRange ("E18");
cell.setFormula("=TRUNC(RANDBETWEEN(100,632))");
```

Any help will be massively appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Tthose are several problems all in one. It's probably best to try to solve it step by step and ask a question for an individual problem when you can't find a solution (and provide sample data)

Comment: indeed too broad. many mistakes that dont match the documentation. example: 'getRange("=VLOOKUP' see the docs on getRange and what it expects as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, your post is too broad.

Anyhow, to help you in any ways, you may use the following as additional references.

1. There's already an existing [issue 456](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=456) in google-apps-script-issues tracker on using bulk methods such as `setValues`, `setFormulas`, etc.
   and based from the thread, this issue hasn't been totally fixed yet. You may, however,  try to use the given work around.
2. For the usage of VLOOKUP in Google Spreadsheets, more information can be found in [Find Data in Google Spreadsheets with VLOOKUP](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/googlespreadsheets/ss/2014-07-07-google-spreadsheets-vlookup-true-function.htm).